# Have something like figure but with its own counter and listof

Tags: floats, xetex, environments

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{grammar}
    <example> ::= \[[ \lit{def} <identifier> \lit{=} <expr> \]]
  \end{grammar}
  \caption{an example grammar}
  \label{grm:example}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

This draws me a nice (partial) definition of the non-terminal “example” in a fictive language and I can see it in the list of figures at the end. But in the real document there are also other figures, which should be in another listofwhatever.

So how can I define such environments by myself with the corresponding counters and lists?

**edit**

If it matters: I am using xelatex 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2013060708 (TeX Live 2013).

Comment: Have a look at the [`float` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality is offered by a number of packages: [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float), [`newfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat), and [`trivfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/trivfloat) for new floating objects.

Here's an example using `newfloat` (refer to the package documentation for the customization options it offers):

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \begin{grammar}
    <example> ::= \[[ \lit{def} <identifier> \lit{=} <expr> \]]
  \end{grammar}
  \caption{an example grammar}
  \label{grm:example}
\end{example}

\listofexamples

\end{document}
```

[image]